# Application.CreateForm() forms visibility / state

Tags: delphi

What's the state of forms created using the TApplication.CreateForm() when creating a multiform VCL applications? Is there a call to a WinAPI that sets them to an invisible state or is it handled by some VCL inner workings?

```
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2); // Invisible
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3); // Invisible
  Application.Run;
```

Comment: They are created (`CreateWindowEx`) without `WS_VISIBLE` style set, secondary forms are shown if they are 'visible' after a possible `OnCreate` event handler is called with a call to `ShowWindow`, interestingly before the main form is shown, which happens in Application.Run.

Comment: In my opinion you should call CreateForm exactly once. It's only purpose is to create the main form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first form that is created using `Application.CreateForm()` will become the application's `MainForm`, and will be shown automatically by `Application.Run()` if `Application.ShowMainForm` is true, the MainForm's `WindowState` is not `wsMinimized`, and the process was not created with the `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` flag specified.

All other forms created by `Application.CreateForm()` will be shown automatically only if their `Visible` property is set to `True`.  By default, the IDE sets the `Visible` property for secondary Forms to `False`.

Please note that auto-creating all Forms on application startup is usually not a good idea. You should remove the second and third Forms from the auto-create list in the Project Options, and then dynamically create them in code when they are actually needed. You can even set your IDE to not auto-create secondary Forms by default.

Comment: Creating the form will always take the same time. If you auto-create all your forms you will always spend that time, regardless of the form being needed or not. The app will therefore just start slower. That's not a good tradeoff IMO.

Comment: I see. But then again if you make multiple calls to secondary forms you will spend even more time creating and destroying the forms for each call. I guess there are tradeoffs either way.

Comment: If you don't destroy them they won't have to be recreated. If you do, then an auto-created form will have to be recreated as well. You can control by setting the `CloseAction` whether a closed form is hidden or destroyed.

Comment: Hmmm, very, very nice. Wasn't aware of that one. `TCloseAction` is the way to go. Thanks mghie.

Comment: This article talks more about CreateForm but it is quite old: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/createform

Comment: "That's not a good tradeoff, IMO". For large(er) applications (over 10-20 forms), I agree with you. It is amazing that the help recommends you to do it the "slow" way. Like... Delphi was designed for small projects :) https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.CreateForm

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Erkennedy/createform) article speaks about the dangers of accessing the form instance in its own OnCreate event handler. One way to avoid this is to refrain to doing any initialization in main form's OnCreate handler. Wait until main form is truly ready. For this send a message to your self. Something like this:

```
const 
   MSG_LateInitialize= WM_APP + 4711;

TMainForm = class(TForm)
    ...
    procedure LateInitialize(var Message: TMessage); message MSG_LateInitialize;
 end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate (Sender: TObject);
begin
 { Send custom message to self }
 PostMessage(Self.Handle, MSG_LateInitialize, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TMainForm.LateInitialize; { This is called only after the main form was fully created }
begin
  init stuff here...
end;
```

It works as long as you don't use the "magic" of Application.ProcessMessage during your app initialization (Hey! Stop using it, not only during your app initialization. Don't use it at all!).

---

PS:
If you look above, there is a lot of boilerplate code necessary to have a basic/correct initialization in place. If Delphi pretends to be safe and easy to use (which it kinda does) it should have provided this kind of functionality for beginners, (hidden) under the hood. Something like a function called AfterApplicationInitialized or AfterFormTrullyCreated :)